# Is there a way to estimate where a ChartLimitLine and a LineChartDataSet intersect on a graph?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I am using the Charts pod library in my app. I have a limit line that intersects a LineChartDataSet and I would like to estimate at what x-value the intersection takes place. I could not find a specific function for this in the library (unless I am missing something), and so I am wondering what the best way to go about trying to do this is?

I am creating the limit line as follows:

```
let line2 = ChartLimitLine(limit: 0, label: "Break-Even")
line2.lineColor = .lightGray
line2.valueTextColor = .lightGray
line2.labelPosition = .topRight
line2.lineWidth = 1
line2.lineDashLengths = [3]
chartView.leftAxis.addLimitLine(line2)
```

And this is how I am adding my data to my chart (there are two series, two lines).

```
var todayDataValues : [ChartDataEntry] = [ ] 
var expiryDataValues : [ChartDataEntry] = [ ] 
for (index, item) in todayValues.enumerated() {
 todayDataValues.append(ChartDataEntry(x: doubleSpots[index], y: item)) 
} 
for (index, item2) in expiryValues.enumerated() { 
expiryDataValues.append(ChartDataEntry(x: doubleSpots[index], y: item2)) 
} 

let set1 = LineChartDataSet(entries: todayDataValues, label: "Today") 
set1.mode = .linear set1.drawCirclesEnabled = false 
set1.setColor(UIColor(named: "TodayLine")!) set1.lineWidth = 3 
set1.highlightColor = .systemGray let set2 = LineChartDataSet(entries: expiryDataValues, label: self.selectedExpiry) set2.mode = .linear 
set2.setColor(UIColor(named: "ExpiryLine")!) set2.lineWidth = 3 
set2.drawCirclesEnabled = false set2.highlightColor = .systemGray let data = LineChartData(dataSets: [set1, set2]) data.setDrawValues(false) 
self.lineChartView.data = data
```

Neither data set has an x value of 0 (where my limit line is), but I am asking how I can make a calculation based on the equation of the line drawn between the two points that *does* intersect 0 - what the x-value might be.

Comment: What have you tried already, please share a [example].

Comment: you need to have formula to find next value of your data, after that you can use that formula to check when they will be intersect, it's not part of any library